# kubectl top node doesn't work. Looks like an issue with heapster

Tags: monitoring, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, metrics

I have a fresh k8s cluster on gke.

Whenever I run `kubectl top node gke-data-custom-vm-6-25-0cbae9b9-hrkc`
I get

```
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource (get services http:heapster:)
```

At the same time I have this service:

```
> kubectl -n kube-system get services
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
default-http-backend   NodePort    10.11.241.20    <none>        80:32688/TCP    59d
heapster               ClusterIP   10.11.245.182   <none>        80/TCP          59d
kube-dns               ClusterIP   10.11.240.10    <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   59d
metrics-server         ClusterIP   10.11.249.26    <none>        443/TCP         59d
```

and a pod with heapster is running (and I can see it was restarted a lot of times)

```
 kubectl -n kube-system get pods
NAME                                               READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
event-exporter-v0.2.3-85644fcdf-kwd6g              2/2       Running   0          16d
fluentd-gcp-scaler-8b674f786-dbrcr                 1/1       Running   0          16d
fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-2fqgl                           2/2       Running   0          17d
fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-47586                           2/2       Running   0          17d
fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-552xm                           2/2       Running   0          16d
heapster-v1.6.0-beta.1-fdc7fd478-8s998             3/3       Running   73         16d
```

However I can see in logs of heapster-nanny container some errors:

```
> kubectl logs -n kube-system --tail 10 -f po/heapster-v1.6.0-beta.1-fdc7fd478-8s998 -c heapster-nanny
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E0418 23:30:10.075539       1 nanny_lib.go:95] Error while querying apiserver for resources: Get https://10.11.240.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/heapster-v1.6.0-beta.1-fdc7fd478-8s998: dial tcp 10.11.240.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E0418 23:30:10.971230       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/autoscaler/addon-resizer/nanny/kubernetes_client.go:107: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://10.11.240.1:443/api/v1/nodes?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.11.240.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E0418 23:30:11.972337       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/autoscaler/addon-resizer/nanny/kubernetes_client.go:107: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://10.11.240.1:443/api/v1/nodes?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.11.240.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E0418 23:30:12.973637       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/autoscaler/addon-resizer/nanny/kubernetes_client.go:107: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://10.11.240.1:443/api/v1/nodes?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.11.240.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E0418 23:30:13.975024       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/autoscaler/addon-resizer/nanny/kubernetes_client.go:107: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://10.11.240.1:443/api/v1/nodes?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.11.240.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E0418 23:30:14.976582       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/autoscaler/addon-resizer/nanny/kubernetes_client.go:107: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://10.11.240.1:443/api/v1/nodes?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.11.240.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E0418 23:30:16.063760       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/autoscaler/addon-resizer/nanny/kubernetes_client.go:107: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://10.11.240.1:443/api/v1/nodes?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.11.240.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E0418 23:30:27.065693       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/autoscaler/addon-resizer/nanny/kubernetes_client.go:107: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://10.11.240.1:443/api/v1/nodes?resourceVersion=0: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E0418 23:30:30.077159       1 nanny_lib.go:95] Error while querying apiserver for resources: Get https://10.11.240.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/heapster-v1.6.0-beta.1-fdc7fd478-8s998: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E0418 23:30:59.778560       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/autoscaler/addon-resizer/nanny/kubernetes_client.go:107: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://10.11.240.1:443/api/v1/nodes?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.11.240.1:443: i/o timeout
```

and also in heapster container

```
I0423 07:02:10.765134       1 heapster.go:113] Starting heapster on port 8082
W0423 07:16:27.975467       1 manager.go:152] Failed to get all responses in time (got 2/3)
W0423 07:16:43.064110       1 manager.go:107] Failed to get kubelet_summary:10.128.0.49:10255 response in time
W0423 07:20:36.875359       1 manager.go:152] Failed to get all responses in time (got 2/3)
W0423 07:20:44.383790       1 manager.go:107] Failed to get kubelet_summary:10.128.0.49:10255 response in time
W0423 07:22:29.683060       1 manager.go:152] Failed to get all responses in time (got 2/3)
W0423 07:22:40.278962       1 manager.go:107] Failed to get kubelet_summary:10.128.0.49:10255 response in time
W0423 07:31:27.072711       1 manager.go:152] Failed to get all responses in time (got 2/3)
W0423 07:31:54.580031       1 manager.go:107] Failed to get kubelet_summary:10.128.0.49:10255 response in time
```

How can I fix this?

Any additional info that I should provide?

Comment: heapter is deprecated and you need to use metric server

Comment: there is metric-server is well, but kubectl top doesn't work still.

Comment: Can you please confirm, if you still observe these errors in your cluster ?

Comment: yes, I still observe these errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Heapster Deprecation

Heapster is a deprecated project and may have problems when running in recent Kubernetes versions.

See [Heapster Deprecation Timeline](https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/heapster/blob/master/docs/deprecation.md):

> ```
> | Kubernetes Release  | Action              | Policy/Support                                                                   |
> |---------------------|---------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
> | Kubernetes 1.11     | Initial Deprecation | No new features or sinks are added.  Bugfixes may be made.                       |
> | Kubernetes 1.12     | Setup Removal       | The optional to install Heapster via the Kubernetes setup script is removed.     |
> | Kubernetes 1.13     | Removal             | No new bugfixes will be made.  Move to kubernetes-retired organization.          |
> ```

Since Kubernetes v1.10, the `kubectl top` relies on **metrics-server** by default.

[CHANGELOG-1.10.md](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.10.md#other-notable-changes-20):

> - Support metrics API in `kubectl top` commands. ([#56206](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/56206), @brancz)
>
> This PR implements support for the `kubectl top` commands to use the
>   metrics-server as an aggregated API, instead of requesting the metrics
>   from heapster directly. If the `metrics.k8s.io` API is not served by the
>   apiserver, then this still falls back to the previous behavior.

---

### What you should do:

As of **Heapster** is deprecated, and you already have a **metrics-server** deployed, the best option is to use a `kubectl` version `v1.10` or above, as it fetches the metrics from metrics-server.

However, beware of [`kubectl` Version Skew Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/version-skew-policy/#kubectl):

> `kubectl` is supported within one minor version (older or newer) of
>   `kube-apiserver`

Check your `kube-apiserver` version before choosing your `kubectl` version.

Comment: Yes, thank you, ugrading kubectl fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your issue might be related to auto-upgrade of your GKE's Master nodes.

Mine got upgraded recently to `v1.11.8-gke.6`, and during the upgrade, I observed the same intermittent errors inside `heapster-nanny` container:

> (error code: E0418)

For me, the problem no longer persists, and I can safely get the nodes' metrics with `kubectl`.